# Shapelets for Cross Sectional Time Series Data

Tags: time-series, panel-data, kalman-filter

I'm currently investigating how to apply shapelet transformations to cross sectional time series (panel) data from this paper: https://www.ismll.uni-hildesheim.de/pub/pdfs/grabocka2014e-kdd.pdf

Say that you have panel data in the following format:

[image: Panel Data Example]

Would it still be possible (or even appropriate) to be able to create shapelets?  Also, could a kalman filter be used if the observation intervals are irregular?  I have only seen discussions of creating shapelets with individual time series with real values.  Any advice or insight would be appreciated!